# Using 2 get controller in mvc

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I need to use 2 get controller to pass data again to my view.I'm getting the data from view and sending it to second controller but ı can't pass it to view again.ViewBag.Model is load in controller ı get error when passing to view.

Controller:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Add()
    {
        FormDetailViewModel model = new FormDetailViewModel();


        foreach(Form item in formRep.List().ProcessResult)
        {
            FormList.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = 
     item.FormId.ToString(), Text = item.TeslimEden });
        }
        foreach(Item item in itemRep.List().ProcessResult)
        {
            İtemList.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = 
       item.ItemId.ToString(), Text = item.ItemDesc });
        }
        foreach(CheckListType item in typeRep.List().ProcessResult)
        {
            TypeList.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = 
      item.CheckListTypeId.ToString(), Text = item.CheckListType1 });
        }
        model.checkLists = TypeList;
        model.FormViewList = FormList;
        model.İtems = İtemList;

        return View(model);
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public ActionResult GetData(FormDetailViewModel model,string input)
    {
        ViewBag.model = input;

        return View(model);
    }
```

View:

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {       <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FormDetail.CheckListType)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => 
 model.FormDetail.CheckListTypeId, Model.checkLists, new { @id = 
 "Selection", 
  @class = "drop-open" })
        <td><button onclick="">Bolum Ekle</button></td>
    </tr>





    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" style="padding-top:40px;">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-info" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>


<h1> @ViewBag.model</h1>
```

JS/jQuery :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#Selection').on('change', function () {
    var info = {
        id: $('#Selection option:selected').text()
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: '/User/FormDetail/GetData',
        type: "GET",
        data: { 'input': info.id },
        success: function (result) {
            console.log(result);
            //$('#ajaxDisplay').html(result);
        }
    });
});
```

GET http://localhost:63081/User/FormDetail/GetData?input=Notlar **500 (Internal Server Error)**

```
send @ jquery.min.js:4
ajax @ jquery.min.js:4
(anonymous) @ open.js:7
dispatch @ jquery.min.js:3
q.handle @ jquery.min.js:3
```

Comment: When it's a 500 error, it's on the server. Are you able to debug it so you can understand the error more precise?

Comment: First ı tried to pass string to my view but i realized i need to pass model because ı need to change something on model now my model return null to me so that s the source of the problem ı guess.

Comment: Are you using using Areas ? if not what's your controller name?

Comment: User = name of the areas , FormDetail =controller's name

Comment: did you debug the controller method break-point hit or not ?

Comment: Yes like ı said.Model return null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting error just because `GetData(FormDetailViewModel model,string input)` GetData required two parameters in your get request you just pass input not model that's why model is null and you pass same model to view `return View(model);` that's cause the problem for you.you just need to pass model to your get request using Ajax otherwise do not pass model to your view. like `return View();`

Comment: So I need return the model to view with ajax . Am ı understand correct ?

Comment: when you make an ajax call you need to pass modal as well like data: { 'input': info.id, 'model': yourmodal },

Comment: Yeah but ı need to post another data with this id.I guess ı will try to do with partial view this way its so challenging.

Comment: yeah if you need view as an Ajax result then you have to use partial view that's better approach.

Answer (score -1):

You are not passing data correctly, make following correction it should work after that.

You don't need to second argument in your action method,as you are getting id in model.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#Selection').on('change', function () {
        var info = {
            id: $('#Selection option:selected').text()
        };

        $.ajax({
            url: '/User/FormDetail/GetData',
            type: "GET",
            data: { 'model': JSON.stringify(info), 'input': info.id },
            success: function (result) {
                console.log(result);
                //$('#ajaxDisplay').html(result);
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Model still returns null

Comment: formDetailViewModel it's modal type not name  this line is not correct. data: { 'formDetailViewModel': JSON.stringify(info), 'input': info.id },